# Notifications of backspace key iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Is there a way to get notifications of when the user presses the backspace key on a UITextField, even if the field is empty?

I would like to be able to trigger some code when the user backspaces on an empty field.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(keyPressed:) name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object: nil];
```

This is how you get notified on every key the user presses. Then you have to figure out (i think in the notification is a property for it) which key was pressed.

Or you can use the textfield delegate function

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

To figure out what key was pressed

Comment: At least for delegation, this won't work on an empty text field.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to detect **not when text was deleted** but when **the backspace key is pressed**, you need to do quite a bit more than implement `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Read [this blog post](http://bjhomer.blogspot.com/2011/11/detecting-backspace-in-uitextfield.html) about how `UITextField` forwards all the `UIKeyInput` methods to a private class `UIFieldEditor`. The writer dynamically subclasses `UIFieldEditor` at runtime in order to detect these events.

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a technique to get you what you want but its going to take a bit of code. In essence, always keep a single Unicode "space" character at the front of the string. I don't have my book with me, but there is a really thin space character you can use.

You will put most of your code here:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

- when the field begins editing, prefix any string there with the space
- when the user appends text as seen in shouldChangeCharactersInRange, append it.
- if the user tries to delete the final last character, or a range that contains it, then return NO, make the change, then add back the leading space char.
- when the textField is finished editing, remove the leading space

Answer (score 0):

This will detect backspace. Now you can do whatever when backspace is pressed.

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        if (textField==txtMobileNo)
        {

            const char * _char = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");

            if (isBackSpace == -8) {
                NSLog(@"isBackSpace");

                if (textField.text.length == 9)
                {

                }

                return YES; // is backspace
            }
            else if (textField.text.length == 10) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }
```